# Exchange with active directory and child domains

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2010

We have the following AD topology:

- ourcompany.com

  - east.ourcompany.com
  - west.ourcompany.com

We are looking to install Exchange in the root ourcompany.com. Are there any issues that we need to be aware of if for users in the child domains east and west?

Can the users in the child domains use the exchange server the same way as the users in the root domain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The child domain users shouldn't have any problems. The user accounts in those domains should be able to be added to and interact with the Exchange server normally.

Caveats I have to note:

1. You will need to set a Recipient Update Service entry specifically for each child domain
2. You will need to run the Exchange setup's domainprep on each child domain.
3. You will probably want to delegate permissions to the domain administrators in the child domains to be able to manage Exchange mailboxes.

Comment: Just to add with the 2013 announcements and all: this setup also works for Office 365 as well, as long as your UPN (@mycompany.com) is the same.